# Simplify $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1-A)(1-B)}{(2-A-B)(A-B)}=\frac{\gamma(\gamma-1)}{2\gamma-1}?$

Tags: limits, gamma-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

Let: 
$$A=\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)$$

$$B=\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}}\right)$$
 **I spent a few days trying to work on the $\gamma$; ([Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant))
I got to this point. It is still look complicated. I need help to simplfy the limit further.**
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1-A)(1-B)}{(2-A-B)(A-B)}=\frac{\gamma(\gamma-1)}{2\gamma-1}\tag1$$

**Can anyone help me to simplfy this limit $(1)?$**

Comment: What do you mean by simplifying? Looks already quite simple to me (if I understood your question correctly).

Comment: That is what I thought but maybe, it can be simplify further.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

I suppose that you need to use (and reuse) the Taylor expansion (have a look at [formula 35 here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html))
$$\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=n-\gamma +\frac{6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2}{12 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\gamma }{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ and then
$$\Gamma(1+\epsilon)= 1-\gamma  \epsilon +\frac{1}{12} \left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) \epsilon
   ^2+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$

It works (a bit tedious).